# Stored procedure returning duplicate rows with one column empty

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[solar_zip_tier_acl_zip_export]
@affiliate_id int
 AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @tier_date  varchar(6)
exec solar_zip_tier_select_active_date @tier_date output

SELECT DISTINCT
    zip,
    state
FROM solar_zip_tier_mapping_view sztm (NOLOCK)
JOIN solar_zip_tier_acl acl (NOLOCK)
    ON acl.tier_id = sztm.tier_id
    AND (acl.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id
    OR acl.buyer_id = 0)
JOIN buyers b (NOLOCK)
    ON b.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id
JOIN solar_zip_tiers szt (NOLOCK)
    ON szt.tier_id = sztm.tier_id
WHERE sztm.tier_date = @tier_date
AND acl.affiliate_id = @affiliate_id
AND sztm.active > 0
AND b.active > 0
AND szt.active > 0
ORDER BY zip
```

The way it returns result is

```
Zip     State

  01001   
  01001   MA

  01002   
  01002   MA

  01003   
  01003   MA
```

It is resulting in 2 rows, one with state in it and other with no state, how do I modify it, so it results only in the row with the data?
I want result as

```
Zip   State

  01001  MA

  01002  MA

  01003  MA
```

Comment: You need to add the table alias to the columns in your SELECT and ORDER BY statements for us to better understand the cause of the issue

Comment: I have a strong suspicion the issue will be with this `AND (acl.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id
    OR acl.buyer_id = 0)`  as ACL.buyer_Id=0 will return record from ACL but may not join to other records B or szt, thus null values.  So what is it you really want here?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    zip,
    state
FROM solar_zip_tier_mapping_view sztm (NOLOCK)
JOIN solar_zip_tier_acl acl (NOLOCK)
    ON acl.tier_id = sztm.tier_id
    AND (acl.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id
    OR acl.buyer_id = 0)
JOIN buyers b (NOLOCK)
    ON b.buyer_id = sztm.buyer_id
JOIN solar_zip_tiers szt (NOLOCK)
    ON szt.tier_id = sztm.tier_id
WHERE sztm.tier_date = @tier_date
AND acl.affiliate_id = @affiliate_id
AND sztm.active > 0
AND b.active > 0
AND szt.active > 0
AND STATE IS NOT NULL AND STATE IS NOT ''
ORDER BY zip
```

Comment: Adding a filter to not return NULLS may get the result looking right, but it is not identifying and correcting the fundamental issue.

Comment: @K Richard, I agree completely with you; we can't help with OP with his/her partial information

Comment: State is not coming null, so this is not working. It is empty

Comment: you need to split your query add joins one by one to see which table / join is causing the unwanted row